# Inquiry regarding digital toggle switches

Tags: digital-logic, switches, toggle-switch

Does there exist a toggle switch (both IRL and in LTSpice) that can take two, mutually exclusive, digital input signals which can toggle it between on and off states?

By mutually exclusive, I mean these two input signals will never be the same/equal.

Comment: Do you want a toggle switch you can switch manually, or do you mean something like a relay or an RS latch?

Comment: A flip-flop I think you might mean.

Comment: @JRE no human intervention/physical contact, it should only be triggered by signals within the circuit.

Comment: @Andyaka I haven't encountered that yet during my studies (I'm no engineering student by any means), so I might read some learning materials regarding that. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments, it seems you need something like an [SR latch.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#Simple_set-reset_latches)

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8JN8Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Normally, both Set and Reset are low.

If you send a high signal to Set, then the output will go high and stay there even when you change Set to a low.

To put the output low, you put a high signal on the Reset input.  The output will then stay low, even when you put reset back to low.

The only thing you are **not** allowed to do is to apply a high to Set and Reset at the same time.

Most simulators will have a built in model of an SR latch.

---

There are other variations.  An SR latch made of NAND gates will require both inputs to be high, with a low used to set the output state.

Comment: Does Set always have to be first? Or does it not matter whether Set or Reset receives the signal first?

Comment: It doesn't matter which it gets first.  The output is undefined when you turn it on, though.  It may be high, or low, or randomly different each time you turn on the power.